# What are some interesting applications of G2/G3 Continuity?

Tags: mechanical, geometry

I've heard of CNC tool paths using splines to approximate G2 continuity to create smoother motion.

Also, rollercoaster designs use G2 continuity to reduce shock from sudden changes in curve radius that would otherwise result from a G1 curve between two sections.

To me this seems like a highly applicable concept, but I haven't found many examples online.

No matter whether the use of continuity is mechanical as in rollercoasters or more of a mathematical exploit in the case of the CNC machine, please share cool applications of G2/G3 continuity below.

The more interesting the better!

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! Unfortunately, this question is very open-ended and so isn't a good fit for the SE format, which is best suited for specific questions with a single, objective answer. I'm therefore closing this question, but encourage you to ask it in our more informal [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20403/the-skunk-works) or on one of the internet's many other traditional engineering forums.